# Vuejs: how to only submit specific form attributes from a vuex store object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having a hard time getting myself out of an endless circle of getting/setting data. I'm sure there is a very obvious solution that I'm for whatever reason completely overlooking.

When a user logs in, I am getting/setting their organization to a vuex store. Everything is working *great*.

I have a settings page where a user can update their organization. I am getting the organization from the store via a computed property. From that computed property, I am populating the form fields when the page loads. Again, everything is working great.

Here is one field from my form to show what I am doing:

Example HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="postalCode" placeholder="45321" 
    :class="{'border-red-500': !$v.organization.zip.required}"
    v-model="organization.zip"
    v-mask="'#####'"
/>
```

Here is my `<script>` block to show how I'm getting my organization data.

```
computed: {
    organization() {
      return this.$store.getters["organization/organization"];
    },
    ...
},
data: () => ({
    errors: false,
}),
validations: {
    organization: {
        name: { required },
        email: { required, email },
        phone: { required },
        streetAddress1: { required },
        city: { required },
        state: { required },
        zip: { required, minLength: minLength(5) },
      },
},
methods: {
    async handleSaveOrganization() {
        this.$v.$touch();

        if (this.$v.$invalid) {
            this.errors = true;
        } else {
            try {
                await this.$store.dispatch("organization/updateOrganization", this.organization)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log("organization was updated!");
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error!');
        }
      }
    },
},
```

I am using [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) as a validation library. The fields in my `validations` object are the fields in my form. The validation is working as well. The issue I am having is submitting the data. **I only want to submit the form fields, not the entire object like I currently am.**

When I fetch the organization from the store, it contains all attributes including `id`, `uuid`, `createdAt` etc. I do not want to include those in my form data.

I am using [NestJs](https://nestjs.com/) for my backend and in my validation rules, I do not allow `uuid` to be sent to the server. Everything is working perfectly -- I'm not sending the data correctly.

Instead of this:

```
{
   id: 122,
   name: "Example",
   email: "example@email.com",
   uuid: 123-44566-3454
}
```

I only want to send the fields that are listed in my validations object.
For example:

```
{
   name: "Example Updated!",
   email: "example@email.com"
}
```

I've tried various ways of destructing or deleting attributes. Each seems to be *really* sketchy.

How can I reliably submit my form without having to do a bunch of seemingly hackish stuff to it? Thank you for any suggestions!

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

Thank you, gijoe for your suggestion. Here's what I came up with for anyone who might come across this.

When I am submitting (making a `PATCH` request) to update my organization, I am sending a dispatch event to my organization vuex store.

From my vuex store, I am calling my organization service. My service now looks like this:

```
updateOrganization(organization) {
    const token = Cookie.get("accessToken");
    const {
      name,
      streetAddress1,
      streetAddress2,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      email,
      phone,
    } = organization;
    const obj = {};

    obj.name = name;
    obj.streetAddress1 = streetAddress1;
    obj.streetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
    obj.city = city;
    obj.state = state;
    obj.zip = zip;
    obj.email = email;
    obj.phone = phone;

    return client
      .patch(`/v1/organizations/${organization.id}`, obj, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("OrganizationService.updateOrganization error: ", error);

        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  },
```

The `organization` argument that is passed in (from the vuex store) still has all of the properties (including id, uuid etc). I needed to be able to get to the id to make the correct `PATCH` request. From there I am creating a temporary object and submitting that. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do the following
Declare a object without attributes
e.x.

```
let org = {};
```

and then an array with all attributes you want to be copied
e.x.

```
 var that = this;
 ['name','email'].forEach(prop=>org[prop]=that.organization[prop]);
```

---

and then send the "org" object instead of this.organization

a 2nd option is to destruct the attributes
e.x.

```
let {name, address} = this.organization;
```

and then initialize a new object from them

```
 let org = {name,address}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That helped me get going in a direction I think I can sustain across the application. I've updated my question with what I came up with. Thank you!